# How do I set the Created Date of a set of files equal to the Modified Date in macOS?

Tags: bash, macos

I'm using the following code in the terminal to change the Created Date of an image file to be equal to the Modified Date:

```
SetFile -d "$(GetFileInfo -m /path/file.png)" /path/file.png
```

This works if I set the path by hand for each file. My issue is that I'm trying to run this update hundreds of files (of multiple image and video formats) in `/path/`.

Here's what I've tried:

Using a For loop:

```
for f in /path/*; do SetFile -d "$(GetFileInfo -m $f)" $f; done
```

Using the Find command to search the directory and apply the SetFile:

```
find /path/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec SetFile -d "$(GetFileInfo -m $f)"  \; > results.out
```

Neither have worked. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say that neither worked, in what way did they not work?  Do you get error messages?  Does it complain about a syntax error?  Does it run but not produce the results you were hoping for?  Does it work for some files but not for others in some fashion?  If you can expand on what you are seeing it will help people know how to help fix things.  (That said, always quote your variables--and in the `find` command you have no `$f` and no argument to `SetFile` for which file to operate on.)

Comment: These both result in the following error: `ERROR: invalid date/time`. I'll fix that second attempt and give it a shot.

Comment: Try adding `set -x` before executing the line, it'll show you what the values look like when they're expanded and about to be executed, perhaps that will give a clue.  Also, please don't put extra information in the comments, instead edit the question to update the information so people who come to the question later can read just the question and get all the necessary information

Comment: See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/445378/on-command-line-what-are-the-successors-of-the-deprecated-getfileinfo-and-setfi/445382#445382

Answer (score 0):

I suspect one or more of the files at `/path/*` have whitespace in the filename.

Try this:

```
for f in /path/*
do
DATE=`GetFileInfo -m "$f"`
SetFile -d "${DATE}" "${f}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in "/path"/*; do SetFile -d "$(GetFileInfo -m $f)" $f; done
```

note that the the path is between "" and the /* is outside of ""

Comment: This duplicates Kaan’s answer. There’s no difference between `/path/*` and `"/path"/*`.